# About co-ordinate problem

Tags: coordinates, pgf-umlcd

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf-umlcd}
\usepackage[a4paper,textwidth=8in,showframe]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \begin{interface}[text width = 6cm]{SG}{-3,3}
    \attribute{\# vocabulary : String}
    \operation{\# addWord(word: String) : Boolean}
    \operation{\# generateSentence(): String}
  \end{interface}

  \begin{class}{RSG}{-8,-4}
    \implement{SG}
    \attribute{\# vocabulary : String}
    \operation{\# addWord(word: String) : Boolean}
    \operation{\# generateSentence(): String}
  \end{class}

  \begin{class}{IOSSG}{-2,-4}
    \implement{SG}
    \attribute{\# vocabulary : String}
    \operation{\# addWord(word: String) : Boolean}
    \operation{\# generateSentence(): String}
  \end{class}

  \begin{class}{OSG}{4,-4}
    \implement{SG}
    \attribute{\# vocabulary : String}
    \operation{\# addWord(word: String) : Boolean}
    \operation{\# generateSentence(): String}
  \end{class}

  \begin{class}{SentenceGenerator}{6,3}
    \operation{+ main(): void}
  \end{class}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

For this code outputs looks like-

[image: 1st image]
In preliminary stage co-ordinate of `SentenceGenerator` was `(6,3)` and `SG` `(-3,3)`. While I was changing co-ordinate of `SentenceGenerator` `(6,4)`, `SG` became drop-down from its initial position.  (i.e.`\begin{class}{SentenceGenerator}{6,4}`).
Now my query is why this happened although co-ordinate of `SG` was not modified?
[image: 2nd image]

Comment: I don't quite understand the problem. Naturally, if `SentenceGenerator` is at y=4, and `SG` at y=3, the latter will be placed lower than the former. ( The boxes are apparently anchored at their tops, so if you place a box at (6,4), the top line of the box is at the y-coordinate of 4.)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. That's because you know that coordinates are relative to the picture and not relative to the page :-).

Answer (score 4):

The way the picture is constructed is that it is put into a box and the box is then placed on the page. When you change the coordinate for`SentenceGenerator`, the box gets a bit bigger because the picture gets a bit bigger. Specifically, its height is increased. So when it is placed, TeX allows more space for it on the page and the box is shifted downwards to make room. The coordinates are not relative to the page, but just relative to other things in the picture (i.e. to other things in this box).

Here's an illustration of the effect:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{every node/.style={draw}}
\begin{document}
\fbox{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node at (0,0) {A};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\fbox{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node at (8,9) {A};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\fbox{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node at (-5,-10) {A};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\fbox{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (o) at (0,0);
    \node at (0,0) {A};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\fbox{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (o) at (0,0);
    \node at (8,9) {A};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\fbox{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (o) at (0,0);
    \node at (-5,-10) {A};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\fbox{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (o) at (0,0) node {.};
    \node at (0,0) {A};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\fbox{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (o) at (0,0) node {.};
    \node at (8,9) {A};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\fbox{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (o) at (0,0) node {.};
    \node at (-5,-10) {A};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\end{document}
```

The first 6 `tikzpicture`s are identical, even though the coordinates of the node containing 'A' vary and even when a coordinate is added first at `(0,0)`. this is because the only bit which counts is the stuff which is drawn. (This isn't quite true, but here it is as if it were true.)

For the variation in the coordinates of the node containing 'A' to matter, we need something else in the picture, so that the distance from the node to the something else changes and not just the nominal position of the node within the coordinate system. If we add a node along with our coordinate at `(0,0)`, we then see the effect of varying the coordinates of the node containing 'A'. The further this node is from the additional node added at `(0,0)`, the bigger the picture has to be to accommodate everything.

[image: coordinate variations]

Comment: if you are true then when I set the co-ordinate of `SentenceGenerator` `(16,3)` why it is out of the page?

Comment: @BandaMuhammadAlHelal First, note that the unit vector is 1cm long. You have `RSG` at `x=-8`, and if you place `SentenceGenerator` at `x=16`, that means it is 24cm further right than `RSG`. An A4 page is 21cm wide ...

Comment: @cfr "When you change the coordinate for `SentenceGenerator`, the box gets a bit bigger because the picture gets a bit bigger". why the picture gets a bit bigger for changing coordination?

Comment: @BandaMuhammadAlHelal Imagine drawing rectangles around everything with the two arrangements. To ensure everything is inside, the rectangle must be larger in one case than in the other i.e. the picture gets bigger.

Comment: @BandaMuhammadAlHelal Again, it is the *relative* dimensions which count i.e. compared with everything else in the picture. If you have a picture with *just* `SentenceGenerator`, it will make no difference whether you put it at `(16,3)`, `(26,3)` or `(-26,-33)`. (As long as the dimensions don't exceed the maximum TeX can deal with, which would give an error.) The coordinates aren't absolute and they aren't relative to the page, but only the rest of the picture.

Comment: @BandaMuhammadAlHelal Please see edited answer above. You can copy-paste the code to play with yourself if you need further convincing :-).

Comment: @cfr I don't understand what you try to say. But my question is why the last node `A(-5,-10)` is set to right of node `A(8,9)`?

Comment: @cfr As LaTeX uses relative coordination then how will I know the x  and y coordination to set a picture at a location? e.g- corner of the page.